# django oscar migrations not migrating, other app migrates

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I've been quite stuck and I've read the docs over and over again. My models aren't migrating. My prompt would be `No changes detected in app "catalogue"` but I did make changes. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Sometimes it works and I don't know why. I make note of it and repeat it, it doesn't work. Any suggestion or idea is appreciated. Thanks!!!

subapp1 is the shop app using oscar, subapp2 is another app

I run `python manage.py makemigrations catalogue` then `python managepy migrate catalogue` I've also tried migrating in the subapp1. Result is the same.

app/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APP = [...] + + get_core_apps(['subapp1.catalogue'])
```

I've also forked the migrations folder as indicated in the docs. I also tried without it. (And yes I have my `__init.py__` file.

app/subapp1/catalogue/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from subapp2 import models as subapp2_models

from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProductImage
from oscar.core.loading import get_model

product = get_model('catalogue','Product')
links = subapp2_models.links

class ProductImage(AbstractProductImage):
    links= models.ForeignKey(links)
    product = models.ForeignKey('catalogue.Product', related_name='photo_links', verbose_name=_("Product"))

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'catalogue'
        verbose_name = _('link image')

    def __str__(self):
        return u"Image of '%s'" % self.product

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into something similar before. There may be a bug with Django migrations, depending on the version you are using. I believe I had problems with 1.8 or 1.9.

The way I resolved it was deleting migrations from the app in question by finding the `migrations` directory and deleting the files in it. Then, I would run `make migrations` and it picked up the changes successfully after that.

Once again, I am not sure if the bug is that of Django itself or just that of the Oscar